# Sensitive Scanner Issue. Prevent Double Scan

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have an application where the user scans a barcode and the form is submitted. Trouble is, the scanners are so sensitive occasionally it double scans so either instead of XXX expected the value would be XXXXXX then the form submits, or the form submits twice in quick succession. I would like to somehow add some pause condition to prevent the sensitive double scan. Any ideas ?

Current Code

```
       <script>
         function validateForm(form) { //This is the name of the function

        if (form.wonumber.value == "OP") { //This checks to make sure the field is not empty
        alert("Cant Submit."); //Informs user of empty field
        form.wonumber.value = ""
        return false; //This prevents the form from being submitted
        }
        return true
        }
        </SCRIPT>

    <form action="outer.asp" method="post" name="form100" id="form100" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <div align="center">
    <span class="style1 style4 style8">
    Scan Parts into Outer <%=request.querystring("id")%>;</span>  
    <p class="style1 style2">
     <input name="wonumber" type="text" id="wonumber" style="height:80px;font-size:50pt;" onChange="return validateForm(this)" size="7">
   </p>
    <p class="style1 style10"><%=description1%>&nbsp;<span class="style1 style2 style10">
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't think the code snippet you provided tells the whole story.  Will you edit your original post and insert the entire code?

Comment: Updated original post to include entire form code.

Comment: Is it an option to simply clear the form if you get more than a maximum amount of characters from your reader?

Answer (score 1):

Your OP has a lot of problems.  What I've done for this example is clean up your markup, removed the stuff that didn't make sense, and wrote some event handlers that will make your `<input>` read-only after the first change.  I believe this will work because I think scanners act just like keyboards.  If it does not work, let me know.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm(form) {
                if (form.wonumber.value == "OP") {
                    alert("Cant Submit.");
                    form.wonumber.value = "";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="outer.asp" method="post" name="form100" id="form100" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
            <span class="style1 style4 style8">Scan Parts into Outer <%= server.htmlencode(request.querystring("id")) %>;</span>
            <input name="wonumber" type="text" id="wonumber" style="height:80px;font-size:50pt;" size="7" onchange="this.readOnly=true">
            <p><%=description1%></p>            
            <button type="button" onclick="form.wonumber.value='carrot'">Carrot</button><br>
            <button type="reset" onclick="form.wonumber.readOnly=false">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```